# Docker Containers cannot communicate with Host Database

Tags: database, docker, networking

I know this question has been asked before, but I haven't managed to solve it from those answers.

**System spec:** I am running the server on Ubuntu 22.10 docker version is 20.10.16 and docker-compose version is 1.29.2

**What I want to achieve:** I have nextcloud running as a docker container and have MariaDB installed on the host machine uncontainerized. I want to use a database I created in MariaDB by nextcloud in docker container. But Hostname is always incorrect, and I get the following error.

> Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

**Troubleshooting I've tried so far**
**Option 1:** I added an extra host to my docker compose file so it can listen to the host system. Here's how my docker compose file like

```
version: '2'


services:
  app:
    image: nextcloud
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /home/ritzz/nextcloud:/var/www/html
    extra_hosts:
    - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
```

However, when adding database if I use `host.docker.internal` as hostname I still get the error mentioned above.

**Option2:** Using docker host IP as database hostname. I used the following command to find out my host ip which was `172.17.0.1`

```
ip addr show docker0
```

However, again adding `172.17.0.1` or `172.17.0.1:3306` returns with the same error.

**Option 3:** I saw an option on the Internet to use `network_mode: host` to make the container use the same network as host. However, since docker container uses port 80 and on my host I can't use port 80. This method won't work for me I assume.

**Additional Troubleshooting**

I made sure Mariadb is with command `sudo systemctl status mariadb` as well as checked that it's listening to port 3306 using command `sudo netstat -tlnp` I also logged in to the database with the user and pass using command `sudo mysql -u<username> -p<password> <database>` and I can login successfully.

I am at the edge with this. Hopefully someone else can help me out

Comment: Keep focusing on `network_mode: host`, it might be your solution.
The port from your host or your container, you can control that through your `docker-compose.yml`.
Log into your docker container and ping the host IP address. do you get a response?

Your host. Is that a Linux system or a Windows system?

Comment: what does `netstat` report in detail? mysql must listen on the docker0 ip too. If mysql ist just listening on `localhost` it wont work.

Comment: Underdog: I added a system spec in the post and added more details. Also I can't change container port in docker-compose file. I can define host port however that won't work if I select network-host 

@SimGel: Yes that could be the issue. MySQL is listening to 127.0.0.1:3306 how do I make it listen to docker0 IP?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/139323/how-to-bind-mysql-server-to-more-than-one-ip-address

Comment: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host '172.23.0.2' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server`
I get this error after changing bind IP to 0.0.0.0